# How can I force users to input a shipping address when using the Commerce Paypal WPS submodule?

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I just built a store in Commerce using Drupal 7 and I am taking payments by the Commerce PayPal WPS submodule.  However, when I tested checkout, I found it was possible to buy a product without supplying a shipping address.

In the [PayPal Express Checkout documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1901466), it shows there is an option for forcing users to provide an address.  However, the [WPS documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1902654) is less comprehensive and does not include any information about whether it is possible to force a shipping address to be displayed or not.

Comment: Do you want to force them to input a shipping address on your site or at PayPal?

Comment: @RyanSzrama At PayPal.  I just need the shipping address in the "payment received" email from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this:

You need to activate the Shipping pane under checkout process:

1. Go to Administration > Store settings > Advanced store settings > Checkout settings (admin/commerce/config/checkout),
2. Check Shipping service under "Checkout pane configuration" or if you use recent version of DC move "Shipping information" pane from disabled panes section to Checkout section,
3. Save.

[image]

If you want to alter data before sending, use the hook_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter(). You need to fetch the customer shipping profile for the current order using commerce_customer_profile_load() and add the values you need from the shipping profile to the $data array.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to the question, I want PayPal to collect the address and include that in the "payment received" email.  I don't want to collect the address on my site.

Comment: Is not possible with WPS payments (at this time), you do retrieve data and sent to PayPal. PayPal Website Payments Standard (WPS) works as follows: Customer fills in name, email, billing and shipping info on the checkout form.

Comment: Update: See WIP on drupal:

 - https://www.drupal.org/node/1494586
 - https://www.drupal.org/node/1872804
 - https://www.drupal.org/node/1301570

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a hook to override this.  By default, Comerce tells PayPal not to collect a shipping address, but you can force this:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_paypal_wps_order_form_data_alter(&$data, $order) {
  // Display a shipping address prompt at PayPal.
  $data['no_shipping'] = 0;
}
```

This way, you don't have to collect the shipping info at your site, but PayPal will still e-mail you the buyer's shipping address.